# Weblogic на Linux 128Gb тормозит, точно такие же настройки на Windows - летает. Что я делают не так?

Tags: weblogic

На сервере настроен кластер на 4 нода с репликацией между ними у каждого в

> server start прописан -Xms22g -Xmx30g
>   в

tuninge прописал

> Self Tuning Thread Maximum Pool Size: 4000 а минимум на 1000

в setDomain тоже прописан был параметрые на 10g мин и 20g на максимум

сам weblogic На linux 128gb ,точно такие же настройки на windowse летала а тут он медленно работает что делаю не так